# Mapping Bluetooth Device

Tags: bluetooth, pi-4, input-device

I have been able to successfully map a USB controller with Raspberry Pi 4 using this tutorial:
https://core-electronics.com.au/tutorials/using-usb-and-bluetooth-controllers-with-python.html

I'm now trying to map a Bluetooth device (called "Chubby Buttons") and am running into issues. I am able to connect the Bluetooth Device to the PI (It is showing the device as connected via the Bluetooth icon as well as when running "sudo bluetoothctl". However, when I run "ls /dev/input", only my keyboard (event0) and mouse are shown, not the Bluetooth "event".

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can get the Bluetooth device to show up as an event so I can map it? Or, is it possible that this device - even though it is paired can't be used with a Pi?

Thank you

Comment: What is the result of this `bluetoothctl` command : `info AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF` when your devices are paired ? (AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF is your BT addr of your controller)

Comment: please fix the broken link to the tutorial

Comment: @Ephemeral I ran the info command and since it showed the appropriate information, I tried running "ls /dev/input" again and it works now as "Event 1".  I'm not sure what the initial issue was, but its all good now.  Thank you